# Are there ways of getting around the cost of atomic operations?

Tags: rust, atomic

I have a counter that's currently an atomic u32 that's used in a hot part of my code, and it's generally just incremented by 1. Very occasionally, it will be read from a very different part of code, but if that does happen, the value must be accurate (at least on the same thread). However, I suspect that that the atomicity may be having bad impacts on performance. An idea I had to address it is to have the main counter be non-atomic, but write atomically to the second counter.

Is an atomic write cheaper than a read? Like does it not need to clear (as much) cache?

Comment: On platforms like x86, loads and stores to atomic variables are the same as non-atomic; what's expensive is the atomic read-modify-write.  So if only one thread will be writing, you may not need the atomic increment at all, at the cost of non-portability.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand your idea: there is one non-atomic counter that's local to the hot thread, an atomic counter that's shared, and you copy the local one to the shared one.  Yes, that should work, and yes, it should be faster.  Reading the shared counter isn't so expensive, but it's better not to have to read it at all (the local one can maybe be kept in a register).

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking; don't actually read from/fetch_add the atomic, just kinda back-up the current state to it. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @NateEldredge Sounds like you could expand those comments into an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### TL;DR

If you have just one writer and one reader threads, all you need is to use atomics with a [relaxed memory ordering or acquire/release](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html#variant.Relaxed).

### Details

On x86 it will be translated to a normal add/mov instructions, so there will be no performance impact.

Here is a normal counter increment:

```
example::normal_inc:
        add     dword ptr [rip + example::normal_u32], 1
        ret
```

Here is an atomic counter increment with relaxed ordering:

```
example::atomic_inc:
        add     dword ptr [rip + example::atomic_u32], 1
        ret
```

There is no difference on x86, hence no performance impact. But is the code correct?

Relaxed loads/stores do not guarantee the ordering across threads, but guarantee the order on the same thread and the atomicity. What does it mean?

For one writer and one reader case it means that if thread `W` updates the counters, thread `R` eventually will see the change, and the value will be valid, as the atomicity is guaranteed. For example, if the counter is 0, and thread `W` increases it to 1, and 2, it's guaranteed thread `R` eventually will see 2, and it will never see 42 or some other random number.

What is not guaranteed is that this number will by aligned with other atomic or non-atomic variables. Say, if thread `W` adds element to a list and then increases the counter, thread `R` might see those events in a reverse order, i.e. first the counter get increased, and then a new element appears in the list.

What is still guaranteed, is the order of events from point of view of thread `W`. Having the same example with a list, it's guaranteed that for thread `W` the list element will appear before the counter get increased, as all of those changes are happening within the same thread, not across different threads.

As x86 has quite strong memory ordering, even aquire/release ordering on the atomics still uses normal add/mov operations. See [memory ordering on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Runtime_memory_ordering).

Acquire/release semantics guarantee not only the atomicity, but also the ordering. Having the example with the list, thread `W` adds a list element, and then `releases` a counter. When thread `R` `acquires` the counter, it's guaranteed that the list element is there. On x86 there is no additional cost for this guarantee.

See also the examples above on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4EsY4j